# How can I change the behavior of tiptap when pasting plain text?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tiptap, prose-mirror

I'm currently trying to implement a visual editor using a library called tiptap.

https://v1.tiptap.dev/

I think v2 is the most common tiptap, but there are circumstances where v1 must be used.

However, I was not satisfied with the behavior when I pasted plain text into tiptap, and when I looked into it, I found that the condition set in the library prosemirror was different from what I expected.

https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror-view/blob/master/src/clipboard.js#L57-L59

```
text.trim().split(/(?:\r\n?|\n)+/).forEach(block => {
 dom.appendChild(document.createElement("p")).appendChild(serializer.serializeNode(schema.text(block, marks)))
})
```

It seems that prosemirror converts a single newline to `<p></p>`.
I would like to change the condition so that it converts to `<br>` if there is one newline, and `<p></p>` if there are two newlines.
But I don't know how to make it happen, and I'm having a very hard time.

```
editorProps: {
  clipboardTextParser(text, $context) {
    console.log(text)
    console.log($context)
    // :(
  }
}
```

I started by using tiptap's `EditorProps` feature to overwrite the entire processing of prosemirror's `clipboardTextParser`.
However, `clipboardTextParser` uses a number of variables and objects in prosemirror, and I have no idea how to write them in editorProps.
And I gave up because I didn't know how to proceed.

Is there any way to solve this?
I'm thinking that if tiptap can do almost the same thing as `clipboardTextParser`, it should be fine.

Pardon my broken English.
Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

You should use transformPastedHTML

https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#view.EditorProps.transformPastedHTML

That will give you a html node then you can simply change the output it like this:

```
private cleanHtmlHanlder (html: string): string {
  const elementHtml = document.createElement('br')
  elementHtml.innerHTML = html

  return elementHtml
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful!